# Loading data from MySQL to table horizontally

Tags: php, html-table

I'm loading some data from MySQL database and it looks like this:

```
| Gray |  S  |
| Gray |  M  |
| Gray |  L  |
| Red  |  S  |
| Red  |  M  |
| Red  |  L  |
```

I want to load data to my table horizontally like this, grouped by color:

```
| Gray |  S  |  M  |  L  |  XL  |
| Red  |  S  |  M  |  L  |  XL  |
```

Here's my code:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($products as $product) {?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $product['color'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product['size'];?></td>
    </tr>       
<?php   }
?>      
</table>
```

Question: how to load data to my table grouped by color per one line? Can I do this without separate MySQL query?

Comment: Honestly this is a presentation issue which would probably be best handled inside PHP, not MySQL.

Comment: I think so too, maybe you have some ideas how to manage it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit of manual iteration would be your friend...

```
$DatabaseResult = [ ['Gray','S'],['Gray','M'],['Gray','L'],['Red','S'],['Red','M'],['Red','L'] ];

$Grouped = array_fill_keys( array_unique( array_column( $DatabaseResult, 0 ) ), array() );

foreach( $DatabaseResult as $row )
{
  $Grouped[ $row[0] ][] = $row[1];
}

print_r( $Grouped );

//Array
//(
//    [Gray] => Array
//        (
//            [0] => S
//            [1] => M
//            [2] => L
//        )
//
//    [Red] => Array
//        (
//            [0] => S
//            [1] => M
//            [2] => L
//        )
//)
```

You would then create two loops, the outer is your "colour" row an the inner is your "size" column

```
<table border="1">
  <?php foreach( $Grouped as $colour => $sizes ) {?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $colour;?></td>
      </td>
      <?php foreach($sizes as $size) {?>
        <td><?php echo $size;?></td>
      <?php } ?>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

---

In addition, if you needed to print a size chart of availability you could do this...

```
$Products = [
  ['color'=>'Gray','size'=>'S','quantity'=>2],
  ['color'=>'Gray','size'=>'M','quantity'=>4],
  ['color'=>'Gray','size'=>'L','quantity'=>7],
  ['color'=>'Red','size'=>'S','quantity'=>8],
  ['color'=>'Red','size'=>'M','quantity'=>6],
  ['color'=>'Red','size'=>'XXL','quantity'=>1],
];

// Helper function to locate products from the array
function SearchProductArray( $products, $color, $size )
{
  foreach( $products as $product )
  {
    if( $product[ 'color' ] == $color and $product[ 'size' ] == $size )
    {
      return $product;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// Locate all the unique Values
$Colours = array_unique( array_column( $Products, 'color' ) );
$Sizes = ['SS','S','M','L','XL','XXL'];

?>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Colour</td>
    <?php foreach( $Sizes as $Size ) {?>
      <td><?php echo $Size;?></td>
    <?php } ?>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach( $Colours as $Colour ) {?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $Colour;?></td>
      <?php foreach( $Sizes as $Size ) { $Product = SearchProductArray( $Products, $Colour, $Size ); ?>
        <td><?php echo ( $Product ) ? $Product['quantity'] : '&nbsp'; ?></td>
      <?php } ?>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Excelent, it works with your array data, but how can I load it with $product['color'] instead 'Gray' or 'Red'?

Comment: Just change `$row[0]` to `$row['color']` etc

Comment: Can you help me out just a little bit more? How can I add $row['quantity'] next to size value, where it says 'Yes'

Comment: @JoeDoe I've updated the second portion of my Answer. I've added a helper function `SearchProductArray` to simplify locating products.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in php. Convert result into array and use for loop instead of foreach loop and you can loop through first column as a row and then second column as a row using counter.

Answer (score 1):

To get the result from MySQL, we could do something like this:

```
SELECT t.color
     , MAX(IF(t.size='S' ,t.size,NULL)) AS size_s
     , MAX(IF(t.size='M' ,t.size,NULL)) AS size_m
     , MAX(IF(t.size='L' ,t.size,NULL)) AS size_l
     , MAX(IF(t.size='XL',t.size,NULL)) AS size_xl
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE ...
 GROUP BY t.color
```

Note that the query only anticipates specific values for size. If we had size 'XS' or 'XXL' in the MySQL table, this query would ignore those values.

So this approach is best suited for columns that have static, well-defined domains (list of valid values).

To get this approach to be more dynamic, and return a result set like shown, we would require a pre-query to get the list of values, and then dynamically construct the SQL statement to be executed.

But once we're headed down that path, it would probably be better to just retrieve the values as they are from MySQL with a simple query, and do the processing in the client to "pivot" the rows into columns for presentation.